# Why does passing a temporary object as an argument need std::move?

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass a string literal array via an initializer list to a function which only accepts `const char**`. Sample code as follows:

```
// Example program 
void foo(const char **) { }

int main() {
    using argType = const char*[];
    foo(argType{"a","b"});
}
```

Which doesn't compile in GCC. The error is:

> In function 'int main()': 6:25: error: taking address of temporary
>   array

I understand that this argument is a temporary which would be cleaned up after executing this `foo(...)` statement. But why is this case considered as an error by the compiler?

Now, if I add `std::move` in between:

```
    foo(std::move(argType{"a","b"}));
```

GCC stops complaining. Why?

Comment: For the record, Clang and MSVC don't complain about both options.

Comment: clang and icc accept both and generate identical machine code for both (with optimizations enabled and non-empty foo). So... gcc bug maybe?

Answer (score 4):

The code is correct; `argType{"a","b"}` is a prvalue of type `const char *[2]`  (C++17 [expr.type.conv]/2) , and the array-to-pointer conversion can be applied to an array prvalue ([conv.array]/1) which performs temporary materialization on the prvalue, and the temporary lasts until the end of the full-expression.

So I think this is a gcc bug.

Comment: What is funny that the [code sample](https://godbolt.org/z/CU-SWH) of `expr.const.cast` contains two "OK" lines, but neither gcc nor clang accepts any.